# Detect OCaml version when compiling C

Tags: c, ocaml

I am working on some code that mixes OCaml and C, the functions `caml_release_runtime_system()` and `caml_acquire_runtime_system()` were introduced in OCaml 3.12 (they were called something else in earlier versions) but I would like to be compatible back to 3.10 if possible, is there an `#ifdef` I can use for that? I have had a look through the headers (in `/usr/lib/ocaml/caml` on my Debian system) and can't find anything that looks like it might. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: this is what I did

This is what I did:

```
#if OCAML_VERSION_MINOR >= 12
#include <caml/threads.h>
#else
#include <caml/signals.h>
#endif 

#ifndef caml_acquire_runtime_system
#define caml_acquire_runtime_system caml_leave_blocking_section
#define caml_release_runtime_system caml_enter_blocking_section
#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ocamlopt` and `ocamlc` binaries supports [`-vnum` and `-version` switches](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual025.html#toc100) for getting the version number:

> **-vnum or -version**
>   Print the version number of the compiler in short form (e.g. 3.11.0), then exit.

This switch is supported in 3.12.0 and the example text in the documentation suggests that 3.11.0 also supports it. I don't have 3.10.0 handy but **nlucaroni** (whose OCaml Fu looks stronger than mine) indicates in the comments that 3.10.0 does have `ocamplopt -version`.

So you could add something like this to your Makefile:

```
OCAML_VERSION_MAJOR = `ocamlopt -version | cut -f1 -d.`
OCAML_VERSION_MINOR = `ocamlopt -version | cut -f2 -d.`
OCAML_VERSION_POINT = `ocamlopt -version | cut -f3 -d.`
```

And then pass those to your compiler using `-DOCAML_VERSION_MAJOR=$(OCAML_VERSION_MAJOR)`, `-DOCAML_VERSION_MINOR=$(OCAML_VERSION_MINOR)`, ...

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 3.11.2. It does work in my version of 3.12.0. `ocamlopt -version` is what I use in my configure script, and it works in 3.10.0 till now.

Comment: Hmm, it does need to work in OCaml from 3.10 to, well, any version above that I guess...

Comment: @nlucaroni, @Gaius: I updated it to use `ocamlopt -version`, does that work for everyone with 3.10?

Comment: added ocamlc as supporting that switch as well.

Answer (score 3):

caml/threads.h:

```
#define caml_acquire_runtime_system caml_leave_blocking_section
#define caml_release_runtime_system caml_enter_blocking_section
```

So simply add that same lines to your C code (guarded with `#ifndef caml_acquire_runtime_system`) and spare your build system (and users) from depending on external utilities and version numbers.

Comment: Nice! I did see those when I was looking though the headers, but it never even occured to me to do that

Comment: Ah, but it would seem that compiling with 3.11 I get `error: caml/threads.h: No such file or directory` so that doesn't work unfortunately